# In R: using leaflet - create an iconList with many icons programmatically

Tags: r, leaflet

I'm using leaflet with R to create an icon set to display on a map, the problem is I can't find a way to do it elegantly with many icons.

This works:

```
myIconList <- iconList(myIcon[[1]], myIcon[[2]], myIcon[[3]], myIcon[[4]])
```

Each list item is an icon.  This would be nice, but it doesn't work:

```
myIconList <- iconList(myIcon)
```

If there's a way to iterate/concatenate into the `iconList`, that would be fine too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I am quite late to the party but I was struggling with this as well and maybe others are too. If you check out the guts of the `iconList` function you see this:

```
function (...) 
{
    res = structure(list(...), class = "leaflet_icon_set")
    cls = unlist(lapply(res, inherits, "leaflet_icon"))
    if (any(!cls)) 
        stop("Arguments passed to iconList() must be icon objects returned from makeIcon()")
    res
}
```

The only thing the `iconList` function is doing is changing the class of the list from `list` to `leaflet_icon_set`. This allows the javaScript underlying leaflet in shiny to properly interact with the list of icons. All you have to do is make your list as you normally would in R and then manually change the class:

```
# assuming myIcon is a list of outputs from makeIcon
class(myIcon) <- "leaflet_icon_set"
```

This worked for me and I hope it works for you too!